# Can ovirt-aaa-jdbc-tool list all users?

Tags: ovirt

Is it possible to list all oVirt users using [`ovirt-aaa-jdbc-tool`](https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-extension-aaa-jdbc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all users from the jdbc providers only using 'ovirt-aaa-jdbc-tool'. You can list them using following command:

`$ ovirt-aaa-jdbc-tool query --what=user`

If you want to list all users in system you need to do it via API. To list all users which are added to the system:

`$ curl -k -u admin@internal:password https://fqdn/ovirt-engine/api/users`

To list all available domains(jdbc domains, as well as LDAP domains) of users in system:

`$ curl -k -u admin@internal:password https://fqdn/ovirt-engine/api/domains/`

To list all users in specific domain:

`$ curl -k -u admin@internal:password https://fqdn/ovirt-engine/api/domains/696E7465726E616C2D617574687A/users`